# Set color for listview javafx

Tags: listview, javafx, colors, set

Please help with ListView coloring.
I have an inner class that updates the list:

```
private class ModelListenerList implements Observer {
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        System.out.println("Show list!");
        if (arg instanceof CouponList) {
            couponList = (CouponList) arg;
            for (Coupon c : couponList.getList())
                System.out.println(c.onHands);
            ObservableList ol = FXCollections.observableArrayList(couponList.list);
            listView.setItems(ol);
        }
        else if (arg instanceof String)
        {
            String e = "";
            System.out.println("TEXT");
        }
    }
}
```

How can i set color for cell with necessary value? List contents objects. Value it is object field

Comment: Return a custom `ListCell` type from `ListView.cellFactory`.

Comment: Can you explain more detail? I just learn java. Or to show where I can read about it